# OS X Automator empty, blank or null value

Tags: macos, automator

I have some data files mostly excel, word and pdf files most of the files have no extension on them. So they are missing the .doc .xls.  This data needs to be used in a Windows environment now.

I have created automator apps for each of the file types I want to add the ext onto.
The problem is it also adds the extension to files that already have an extension.
So data.xls becomes data.xls.xls
I would like to figure a way to only add the extenion to the files without extension.

How do I tell the finder filter that i only want it to return files without extensions.
I see how to add a line to filter by extension but I don't know how to let it know I want only blank or null or files without any extensions.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us some code then?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. There is an option to change files with no extension.

http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/changeextensions.html